Correct numbering of Figures and Equations when Using 'Parts' and 'chapters'
strong textI am currently writing my thesis. I have formatted it by having several 'parts' and within that 'chapters'. At the beginning of the 'part' I give an overview of the coming chapters. I include a couple of equations or figures. The references for these use the previous chapter number that occurred before the 'part'. I.e. in Part I, I am giving an overview of Chapters 2 to 4. However the equations begin with 1.1 or 1.2 and so on. Additionally, in the list of figures, the figures appear in the previous 'part' under the previous chapter.
I could include an additional chapter at the beginning of the 'part' but as it is only a one-page summary, the formatting doesn't look very nice.
Any help would be much appreciated! :)
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\examplefig{\begin{figure}\caption{Figure}\end{figure}}

%
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{First Chapter}
%
\examplefig
\examplefig
\part{Part I}
Text to explain the overview of this part. An equation that is relevant to the following chapters:
\examplefig
The above Figure is 1.3 and I would prefer it to be 2.1. However, I do not want to create a chapter here that is only 1 page long giving an overview of the chapters that follow. I want the figure to be labelled so I can refer to it in this and following sections. 
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\examplefig
\examplefig
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\chapter{Fourth Chapter}
%
\part{Part II}
Text to explain the overview of this part.
\chapter{Fifth Chapter}
\chapter{Sixth Chapter}
\end{document}

I have edited the above question to try and clarify the issue as the original document was too simplified so lost some of the relevant behaviour
Below I have attempted to solve it using a very good suggestion about setting the chapter to a certain number. The issue of it appearing in the list of figures still persists in this case. While the numbering is improved, the Figure goes from 2.3 then to 2.1:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\examplefig{\begin{figure}\caption{Figure}\end{figure}}

%
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{First Chapter}
%
\examplefig
\examplefig
\part{Part I}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
Text to explain the overview of this part. An equation that is relevant to the following chapters:
\examplefig
The above Figure is 1.3 and I would prefer it to be 2.1. However, I do not want to create a chapter here that is only 1 page long giving an overview of the chapters that follow. I want the figure to be labelled so I can refer to it in this and following sections. 
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\examplefig
\examplefig
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\chapter{Fourth Chapter}
%
\part{Part II}
Text to explain the overview of this part.
\chapter{Fifth Chapter}
\chapter{Sixth Chapter}
\end{document}


it would be less confusing to use \[ and unnumbered equations, but you could  add 1 to the chapter counter at the start of the part, then subtract 1 before the chapter if you really want what you ask for.

Hi David, thanks so much for the idea! I want to keep figures numbered because I go on to reference them at later stages. Your idea about the counter was really great. I have tried it but seem to have the issue that the Figures continue the numbering from the previous chapter and also still appear in the 'wrong' section of the list of figures. I have changed the question to give a better example of the behaviour as I oversimplified the previous example. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond! :)

I see an answer has been posted but consider your readers, seeing a figure or equation numbered as part of chapter 2 before chapter 2 starts is just confusing.  Do you have any existing publication that does that? I would un-number them, if you need to reference them you could use \tag{..} with some custom label that doesn't imply a chapter \tag{\dagger} or some such.

I had chosen numbering it as chapter 2 as a lesser of two evils (at least it belonged to the correct part that way). I wasn't aware of the \tag command. That solution is miles better! Thank you. The solution I have used is  \tag{II.1} , \tag{II.2} and so on.
I still have the issue that in the \listoffigures it places the tagged figures in the previous chapter. This seems different from my original question so I will do some further research and see if I can find a solution. Thank again so much for your advice.

This alternates between \thepart and \thechapter as needed.
Note that \chapter adds a \vskip 10pt in the list of figures, but \part does not, even though it is a bigger division.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\examplefig{\begin{figure}\caption{Figure}\end{figure}}
%
\usepackage{etoolbox}% for \patchcmd
\newcounter{mutant}[part]% resets to zero when part in incremented
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\refstepcounter{chapter}}% increment mutant in each chapter
  {\refstepcounter{chapter}\stepcounter{mutant}}{}{}%
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\themutant}{\ifnum\value{mutant}=0\relax
    \thepart
  \else
    \thechapter
  \fi}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\themutant.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\themutant.\arabic{figure}}% etc,
%
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{First Chapter}
%
\examplefig
\examplefig
\part{Part I}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
Text to explain the overview of this part. An equation that is relevant to the following chapters:
\examplefig
The above Figure is 1.3 and I would prefer it to be 2.1. However, I do not want to create a chapter here that is only 1 page long giving an overview of the chapters that follow. I want the figure to be labelled so I can refer to it in this and following sections. 
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\examplefig
\examplefig
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\chapter{Fourth Chapter}
%
\part{Part II}
Text to explain the overview of this part.
\chapter{Fifth Chapter}
\chapter{Sixth Chapter}
\end{document}


Hi John, thanks so much for taking the time to respond and help with my question, especially as it isn't an approach you would recommend yourself!
I implemented your suggestion which worked well for the example I gave but I realised that the example didn't properly capture all the relevant features of my thesis document. I have updated the question to reflect that so thanks so much for your response as that helped me improve the question. Once again thanks so much for your time!
